# Rails belongs_to issue in the views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Im having problems with an association in rails:

Currently I have Post and User models, and the relationship is set this way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :name, :lastname
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body
  belongs_to :user
end
```

However, in my app/views/posts/index.html.haml when Im trying to access the username for the post I get this error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

This is my view:

```
- title "Posts"

%table
  %tr
    %th Title
    %th Body
    %th Author
  - for post in @posts
    %tr
    %td= h post.title
    %td= h post.body
    %td= h post.user.name
    %td= link_to 'Show', post
    %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post)
    %td= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete

%p= link_to "New Post", new_post_path
```

Any thoughts of what Im doing wrong will be appretiated

Comment: will u show me the code in action part.

Comment: It looks like there is one (or more) `Post` model in `@posts` that doesn't have a user set.

Comment: @piemersons the controller?

    def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

Comment: @daniel How can I add the relationship them? I though rails did it automagicly

Comment: How are you saving your post?

Comment: @daniel thanks for the hint!, I wasn't saving the user, so I did the following:

@post = Post.new(params[:post])
    @post.user = User.find(2)
    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post."
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end

And now it works, now I need to change the User.find method with the current logged user.

Comment: Using `collection.build` (see my answer) would be a more "Rails"-y way to do it, but yes, setting @post.user directly will work. Also, for future reference, when you're adding code it's better to do it as an edit on your question where it can be formatted than in a comment :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all check if `posts` table has a column named `user_id` (you can lookup this table in db/schema.rb)

If not, you probably need to create a migration:
`$ ruby script/generate migration AddUserIdToPosts`

```
class AddUserIdToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :posts, :user_id
  end
end
```

And then apply changes to the database and schema.rb
`$ rake db:migrate`

Comment: Hi Andrew,

I did not have the user_id column so I added it, however I still get the following error:

    undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I solved it with saving the user along with the post like this:

@post = Post.new(params[:post])
    @post.user = User.find(2)
    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post."
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end

Now Im changing the User.find to current logged user, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, it looks like you are not associating the actual `User` **data** with the `Post` **data**. You have the associations set up, and after Andrew's answer you seem to now have the database schema set up, but you are not saving the data anywhere.

To do so, update your create method to be something like this:

```
def PostsController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    # Assumes @user is already set to whatever user should be associated with the post
    post = @user.posts.build(params[:post]) # Where params[:post] are the post inputs from your form
    # ...
    if post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post."
      redirect_to post
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

`@user.posts.build` tells Rails to create a new Post (in memory) and associate it to the `@user` User model. An equivalent (but lengthier) way of expressing this is:

```
post = Post.new(post[:params])
post.user = @user
```

See the documentation for [ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001316) for more information about what you can do with associations.